# Как добавить к заголовку в битриксе title дополнительное свойство товара

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс

Всем привет, есть заголовок h1 такого рода в него я вывел текст из свойства который прописал в карточке товара, все работает, но теперь мне нужно сделать так что бы в title эти заголовки объединялись, а так же в meta og:title тоже был общий и конечно же добавлять свойство в ЧПУ как это можно сделать, если поможет то используется готове решение Аспро лайтшоп. Если есть примеры похожего решения как можно делать два заголовка то я был бы признателен.

```
<h1>
<div class="font_22 switcher-title js-popup-title font_20--to-600"><?=$elementName;?> </div>
<div class="font_32 switcher-title js-popup-title font_20--to-600"><?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['SEO_URL']['VALUE']?> </div>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

На странице SEO нужного инфоблока можно указать шаблон для META TITLE. Например:

```
{=this.Name} {=this.property.SEO_URL}
```

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=34&LESSON_ID=6305

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=34&LESSON_ID=5840

Comment: Это я нашел, но вот пока что не нашел решения по крошкам